# I want to to create a item slider where, when I hover over the item a modal exactly over it and it should not affect other content on the page

Tags: html, jquery, css, hover, slider

-please consider the slider as working slider and below structure is just sample. I was not sure where to add  so I didn't mention it.
-modal will contain information related to hovered item.

- Each item had its own modal.
  -I would like to create NETFLIX like hover effect.
  -I have watched and tried with the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rR1uIN-Mes4) it certainly worked but it affects other content on-page, liked it pulls content of below section.
  Here is some HTML code:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Css

```
.slider{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
.item{
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#232323;
  margin-right:15px;
}
.item:last-child{
  margin-right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for (if I understand your question) is the `transform` property in CSS. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). I also used the `transition` property to make the effect animate smoothly (which you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)).

I included an example below.

```css
.slider{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
.item{
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#232323;
  margin-right:15px;
  
  /* make the transform effect the element smoothly */
  transition: transform 0.15s;
}
.item:last-child{
  margin-right:0;
}

/* act on element hover */
.item:hover {
  /* scale up the hovered item 1.15x */
  transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

***Note:** if you want to keep the scrollbars from appearing around the elements, you can use `overflow: hidden;` on the item group's container.*

Answer (score 0):

I have created a slider as you have mentioned. Though my project is old and use bootstrap 3 you can change it to.
Below I am sharing my code to you in which you can see and here in my code I have used owl carousel so it's up to you whatever carousel you may like you can use it
On Hover of image you find modal with carousel

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
       
            $("#image-link").hover(function () {
              
                $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
            }); 
        


        if ($('.comittee-carousel').length) {
            $('.comittee-carousel').owlCarousel({
                loop: true,
                margin: 30,
                nav: true,
                smartSpeed: 700,
                autoplay: true,
                navText: ['<span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>', '<span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>'],
                responsive: {
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    },
                    767: {
                        items: 1
                    },
                    991: {
                        items: 1
                    },
                    1024: {
                        items: 1
                    },
                    1200: {
                        items: 1
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" integrity="sha512-OTcub78R3msOCtY3Tc6FzeDJ8N9qvQn1Ph49ou13xgA9VsH9+LRxoFU6EqLhW4+PKRfU+/HReXmSZXHEkpYoOA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" integrity="sha512-UTNP5BXLIptsaj5WdKFrkFov94lDx+eBvbKyoe1YAfjeRPC+gT5kyZ10kOHCfNZqEui1sxmqvodNUx3KbuYI/A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js" integrity="sha512-gY25nC63ddE0LcLPhxUJGFxa2GoIyA5FLym4UJqHDEMHjp8RET6Zn/SHo1sltt3WuVtqfyxECP38/daUc/WVEA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/376464/pexels-photo-376464.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" class="card-img-top" style="width:500px;" alt="..." id="image-link" />
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModal1Labe" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModal1Labe">Image Title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="comittee-carousel owl-carousel owl-theme">

                        <div class="comittee-block">
                            <div class="inner-box">
                                <div class="image-box">
                                    <figure><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1624487/pexels-photo-1624487.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt=" " style="width:300px;" class="carousel-img"/></figure>
                                </div>
                                <div class="lower-content">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Image 1</a></h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="comittee-block">
                            <div class="inner-box">
                                <div class="image-box">
                                    <figure><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/70497/pexels-photo-70497.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt=" " style="width:300px;" class="carousel-img"/></figure>
                                    <!--<div class="overlay-box"><a href="#">Read More</a></div>-->
                                </div>
                                <div class="lower-content">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Image 2</a></h3>
                                    <!--<div class="text">Acepteur sintas haecate sed ipsums cupidates nondui proident sunlt culpa qui tempore officia sed ipsum tempor eserunt.</div>-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="comittee-block">
                            <div class="inner-box">
                                <div class="image-box">
                                    <figure><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1099680/pexels-photo-1099680.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt=" "style="width:300px;"  class="carousel-img"/></figure>
                                </div>
                                <div class="lower-content">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Image 3</a></h3>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="comittee-block">
                            <div class="inner-box">
                                <div class="image-box">
                                    <figure><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/958545/pexels-photo-958545.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" style="width:300px;" class="carousel-img"/></figure>
                                </div>
                                <div class="lower-content">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Image 4</a></h3>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```